# How to create inline_keyboard using json with multiple InlineKeyboardButton on same row?

Tags: json, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Looking for json payload to create `inline_keyboard` with multiple `InlineKeyboardButton` on the same row.

The following code is working but creates 1 button per row.

```
{
  "telegram": {
    "text": "Pick a color",
    "reply_markup": {
      "inline_keyboard": [
        [
          {
            "text": "Red",
            "callback_data": "Red"
          }
        ],        
        [
          {
            "text": "Pink",
            "callback_data": "Pink"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Telegram Card in Dialogflow is able to create multiple inline buttons similar to as shown below:

[image: inline_keyboard with inline buttons]

https://core.telegram.org/file/811140217/1/NkRCCLeQZVc/17a804837802700ea4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline_keyboard` [consists of rows](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup), each row consists of [buttons](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton).

So just add buttons to the first row (`Blue` and `Green` in this case) like this:

```
{
  "telegram": {
    "text": "Pick a color",
    "reply_markup": {
      "inline_keyboard": [
        [
          {
            "text": "Red",
            "callback_data": "Red"
          },
          {
            "text": "Blue",
            "callback_data": "Blue"
          },
          {
            "text": "Green",
            "callback_data": "Green"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan for a quick reply, it worked as expected.